# Displaying selected items in dropdowns to a grid view

Tags: asp.net

I have 3 dropdowns. when selecting an item from first ddl,second ddl generated with respective items. When selecting second ddl,third ddl generated with respective data. My problem is that when selecting an item from third ddl, 3 items(selected item of 1 ddl,selected item of 2 ddl,selected item of 3 ddl) need to display in a grid view. How to achieve that?
aspx page:

```
  <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCountry" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem>--Select-- </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>India</asp:ListItem>

    <asp:ListItem>Australia</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Pakistan</asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLState" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLState_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList> 


<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="Grd1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

aspx.cs page

```
   protected void DDLCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DDLCity.Items.Clear();
    DDLState.Items.Clear();
    if (DDLCountry.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        DDLState.Items.Add(new ListItem("select", "0"));
        DDLState.Items.Add(new ListItem("Kerala", "1"));
        DDLState.Items.Add(new ListItem("AP", "2"));
        DDLState.Items.Add(new ListItem("Karnataka", "3"));



    }
    else if (DDLCountry.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        DDLState.Items.Add(new ListItem("select", "0"));
        DDLState.Items.Add(new ListItem("Victoria", "1"));
        DDLState.Items.Add(new ListItem("Western Australia", "2"));
        DDLState.Items.Add(new ListItem("New South Wales", "3"));


    }
    else if (DDLCountry.SelectedIndex == 3)
    {
        DDLState.Items.Add(new ListItem("select", "0"));
        DDLState.Items.Add(new ListItem("Balochstan", "1"));
        DDLState.Items.Add(new ListItem("Sindh", "2"));
        DDLState.Items.Add(new ListItem("Punjab", "3"));

    }


}
protected void DDLState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DDLCity.Items.Clear();
    if ((DDLCountry.SelectedIndex == 1) && (DDLState.SelectedIndex == 1))
    {
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("Calicut", "0"));
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("Kochi", "1"));

    }
    else if ((DDLCountry.SelectedIndex == 1) && (DDLState.SelectedIndex == 2))
    {
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("Hyderabad", "0"));
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("Vijayawada", "1"));
    }
    else if ((DDLCountry.SelectedIndex == 1) && (DDLState.SelectedIndex == 3))
    {
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("Bengaluru", "0"));
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("Mysore", "1"));
    }
    else if ((DDLCountry.SelectedIndex == 2) && (DDLState.SelectedIndex == 1))
    {
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("Melbourne", "0"));
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("A", "1"));
    }
    else if ((DDLCountry.SelectedIndex == 2) && (DDLState.SelectedIndex == 2))
    {
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("Perth", "0"));
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("B", "1"));
    }
    else if ((DDLCountry.SelectedIndex == 2) && (DDLState.SelectedIndex == 3))
    {
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("Sydney", "0"));
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("C", "1"));
    }
   else if ((DDLCountry.SelectedIndex == 3) && (DDLState.SelectedIndex == 1))
    {
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("Lahor", "0"));
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("D", "1"));
    }
    else if ((DDLCountry.SelectedIndex == 3) && (DDLState.SelectedIndex == 2))
    {
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("Karachi", "0"));
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("E", "1"));
    }
    else if ((DDLCountry.SelectedIndex == 3) && (DDLState.SelectedIndex == 3))
    {
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("Peshawar", "0"));
        DDLCity.Items.Add(new ListItem("F", "1"));
    }


}
```

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: It completely depends on which asp.net + client side technology you are using, webforms ? MVC ? Is their any javascript or it's all callbacks ?
Submit your code

Comment: @Massanu only webforms

Comment: Add the gridview population in the third DDL selected item event does not work ?

Comment: @Massanu Plz provide code

Comment: You would be better off giving each state a unique value and using that value to determine which cities to show. For example, the indian states have values 1,2 and 3, the australian ones have 4,5 and 6 etc. Then on DDLState_SelectedIndexChanged your if statements (or a switch) are simplified.... e.g. if(DDlCountry.SelectedValue == "1")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void DDLCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = null;
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));

dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Column1"] = DDLState.SelectedItem.Text;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Column1"] = DDLCountry.SelectedItem.Text;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Column1"] = DDLCity.SelectedItem.Text;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dbGridView.DataSource = dt;
dbGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a sample for you Maybe it helps:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

And the cs code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public Random r;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        r = new Random();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                int n = r.Next(100, 200);
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(n.ToString(), n.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int n = r.Next(300, 400);
            DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem(n.ToString(), n.ToString()));
        }
    }
    protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int n = r.Next(500,600);
            DropDownList3.Items.Add(new ListItem(n.ToString(), n.ToString()));
        }
    }
protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Column1"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        dr["Column2"] = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;
        dr["Column3"] = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }

}
```